# Vlookup from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to vlookup data from another workbook. I am pulling with file name in vlookup and I want to make it dynamic. Here is my code:

```
Dim INPUT_PATH As String
Dim WBK As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

INPUT_PATH = Sheet3.TextBox1.Text

Set WBK = Workbooks.Open(INPUT_PATH)
WBK.Windows(1).Visible = True

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="nch"
Range("B6").Select

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("D10").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,2,0)
Range("G10").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,3,0)
Range("D12").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,4,0)
Range("G12").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,5,0)
Range("D14").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,6,0)
Range("G14").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,7,0)
Range("F16").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[Rate.xlsx]Asset Depreciation'!$C:$J,8,0)
```

Comment: *"i want to make it dynamic"* - In what way? Please be more specific.

Comment: i need a help on vlookup formula here.. i am pulling the vlookup formula from another workbook and in future the file or sheet name might be changed.. if we use varible to pull the formula even the file or sheet name changes it will affect the coding.. pls help on vlookup formula here

Comment: If you have those formulas in place and then change the file or sheet name, the formulas should auto-update.

Answer (score 2):

As follows?

```
Dim fileName As String, sheetName As String
fileName = "Rate.xlsx"
sheetName = "Asset Depreciation"

Range("D10").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G8,'[" & fileName & "]" & sheetName & "'!$C:$J,2,0)"
```